# Read user input and send it to MySQL

Tags: mysql, linux, bash, scripting

So I am attempting to make my first Linux script and its just to setup a MySQL user and I'm trying to do that all with a script, but I can not seem to find how I can send the MySQL command from the script. This is what I have right now.

```
#!/bin/bash  
read -p "Please enter your desired MySQL username:  " USER
    echo $USER
read -p "Please enter your desired MySQL password:  " PASS
    echo $PASS
mysql CREATE USER $USER@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY $PASS;
```

any help would be appreciated

Thanks
-Jamie

Answer (score 0):

You cannot mixup mysql queries in bash script.So, you have to save the mysql queries to a mysql file i.e .sql file and then run the mysql command

To append the create user line to a .sql file use

`echo 'mysql CREATE USER $USER@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY $PASS' >> filename.sql`

Now the .sql file will contain the sql queries and you can run

`$ mysql -h "server-name" -u "root" "-pXXXXXXXX" "database-name" < "filename.sql"`